# Bootstrap Grid displays as text

Tags: css, bootstrap-grid

SOS! I'm trying to create a grid.
But I keep seeing this instead. Any idea why this happens? How can we fix this?

[image]

Comment: Can you post the code,so I can help you

Comment: Be sure you are loading bootstrap CSS file